# Matplotlib doesn't show my graph (using vim)

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7, google-chrome-os

I'm having a problem with matplotlib. I'm using the linux Chrome OS distro. When I try to creat a graph, it doesn't show me anything, just this:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYFfO.png)

This is the script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
x = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
bin = [10]
plt.hist(x,bin)
plt.show()
```

My IDE is Vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because you supplied the wrong argument to `plt.hist`. According to the documentation:

```
bins : int or sequence or str, default: :rc:`hist.bins`
    If *bins* is an integer, it defines the number of equal-width bins
    in the range.

    If *bins* is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the
    left edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin;
    in this case, bins may be unequally spaced.  All but the last
    (righthand-most) bin is half-open.  In other words, if *bins* is::

        [1, 2, 3, 4]

    then the first bin is ``[1, 2)`` (including 1, but excluding 2) and
    the second ``[2, 3)``.  The last bin, however, is ``[3, 4]``, which
    *includes* 4.

    If *bins* is a string, it is one of the binning strategies
    supported by `numpy.histogram_bin_edges`: 'auto', 'fd', 'doane',
    'scott', 'stone', 'rice', 'sturges', or 'sqrt'.
```

So by supplying `[10]`, you haven't supplied the end of a bin, only the start, and nothing is generated. You can fix this with `plt.hist(x,10)` or `plt.hist(x, [10, 20, 30 <rest>])`.

In addition, try to avoid overwriting builtin functions like `bin`. It won't affect you now, but might haunt you later.

Comment: Sorry for my noobness, but can you link the documentation? It could be usefull in the futrue and I ask any stupid questions

Comment: Sure, here's the link to hist: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html